# Не удается добавить блок в низ страницы

Tags: html, css

На странице есть три колонки, с лева блоки, в центре инфа, справа блоки.

Получается что слева блоков намного больше, и они занимают большее пространство, которое уходит ниже.

И вот мне нужно разместить в самом низу страницы div блок, но получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот эта красная линия и есть тот самый блок который я хочу поместить в самый низ страницы...
 Не понимаю в чем проблема...
Разметка страницы:

```
    <div id="container">

    <div id="nav">
    //тут левые блоки
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
    //тут анфа по центру
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
    //тут правые блоки
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div> //нижний блок

.footer {
background: red;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 7px;
padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит из-за свойства float, container теряет свою высоту из-за плавающих дочерних элементов, и чтобы очистить поток используется, так называемый, clearfix. Т.е. вам нужно прописать для #container следующее:

```css
#container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```